# How to make Square Text box in jQuery mobile?

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, textbox

I'm creating a mobile app using jQuery mobile. I need to create an editable text table. So I have decided to create a table and inserting text box into it.

It's working But the textbox is in a different shape which is default for Jquery mobile.

Comment: Also, providing your code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

Specific text input:

```
#text {
    border-radius: 0 !important;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/LqDke/

Everything:

```
.ui-corner-all {
    border-radius: 0 !important;
}
```

**EDIT :**

Or you can do it like this:

```
$('a').buttonMarkup({ corners: false });
```

## Final notes

If you want to find more about how to customize jQuery Mobile page and widgets then take a look at this **[article](http://www.gajotres.net/learn-how-to-customize-jquery-mobile-application/)**. It comes with a lot of working examples, including why is !important necessary for jQuery Mobile.

Comment: Thanks a lot bro.. Can u also please tell me how i can fit the textbox into the table completely?

Comment: Are you using jQuery mobile resizable table or some other implementation?

Comment: Hey.. Just now checked and it`s working... Now I am going to adjust the width and heigh of the table.. Thank you

Comment: Text box should fit by it self, only thing to do here is to remove its margin with this: .ui-input-search, div.ui-input-text {
 margin: 0 !important;
}

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ui-corner-none` class

```
<input class="ui-corner-none" type="text">
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the styling actually gets applied to the div that encloses the input, rather than the input itself, don't try to style it after the fact. Use the data-attribute: data-corners="false" on the input and let jquery mobile handle it natively:

```
<input type="number" size="2" data-corners="false">
```